# How to pass keywords list to pathos.multiprocessing?

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, keyword-argument, pathos

I am using pathos.multiprocessing to parallelize a program that requires using instance methods. Here is a minimum working example:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from pathos.multiprocessing import Pool, ProcessingPool, ThreadingPool

class dummy(object):
    def __init__(self, arg, key1=None, key2=-11):

        np.random.seed(arg)

        randnum = np.random.randint(0, 5)

        print 'Sleeping {} seconds'.format(randnum)
        time.sleep(randnum)

        self.value = arg
        self.more1 = key1
        self.more2 = key2

args = [0, 10, 20, 33, 82] 
keys = ['key1', 'key2']
k1val = ['car', 'borg', 'syria', 'aurora', 'libera']
k2val = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
allks = [dict(zip(keys, [k1val[i], k2val[i]])) for i in range(5)]

pool = ThreadingPool(4)
result = pool.map(dummy, args, k1val, k2val)

print [[r.value, r.more1, r.more2] for r in result]
```

The result printed is (as expected):

```
Sleeping 4 seconds
Sleeping 1 seconds
Sleeping 3 seconds
Sleeping 4 seconds
Sleeping 3 seconds
[[0, 'car', 'a'], [10, 'borg', 'b'], [20, 'syria', 'c'], [33, 'aurora', 'd'], [82, 'libera', 'e']]
```

However, in this call to `map` the order of the last two arguments matters, and if I do:

```
result2 = pool.map(dummy, args, k2val, k1val)
```

I obtain:

```
[[0, 'a', 'car'], [10, 'b', 'borg'], [20, 'c', 'syria'], [33, 'd', 'aurora'], [82, 'e', 'libera']]
```

whereas I would like to obtain the same as the first result. The behaviour would be the same as what `apply_async` `kwds` can do in the standard module `multiprocessing`, i.e. pass a list of dictionaries, where in each dictionary the keys are the keyword names and the items are the keyword arguments (see `allks`). Notice that the standard module `multiprocessing` cannot use instance methods, and therefore does not meet even the minimum requirements.

Tentatively this would be:
    result = pool.map(dummy, args, kwds=allks) # This does not work

Answer (score 9):

I'm the `pathos` author.  Yeah, you hit on something that I have known needs a little work.  Currently, the `map` and `pipe` (i.e. `apply`) methods from `ProcessPool`, `ThreadPool`, and `ParallelPool` cannot take `kwds` -- you have to pass them as `args`. However, if you use `_ProcessPool` or `_ThreadPool`, then you can pass `kwds` to their `map` and `apply` methods.
The pools in `pathos.pools` that start with an underscore actually come directly from `multiprocess`, so they have identical APIs to those in `multiprocessing` (but with better serialization, so can pass class methods etc).

```
>>> from pathos.pools import _ProcessPool
>>> from multiprocess.pool import Pool
>>> Pool is _ProcessPool
True
```

So, for the edits to the original code would look something like this (**from the OP's suggested edit**):

```
>>> from pathos.pools import _ThreadPool
>>> pool = _ThreadPool(4)
>>> 
[…]
>>> result = []
>>> def callback(x):
>>>    result.append(x)
>>>
>>> for a, k in zip(args, allks):
>>>     pool.apply_async(dummy, args=(a,), kwds=k, callback=callback)
>>> 
>>> pool.close()
>>> pool.join()
```

Comment: a heartfelt oversize thank you for putting time and effort in developing `pathos`. Additional kudos for addressing my specific issue.